# Endpoint to determine region of Microsoft Azure API Key

Tags: r, azure, http, azure-cognitive-services, httr

I'm working on an R package, [mscstts2](https://github.com/howardbaek/mscstts2), that makes HTTP requests to the [Microsoft Text to speech REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming)

I'm wondering if Microsoft has an endpoint, such as the `issueToken` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/rest-text-to-speech?tabs=streaming#how-to-get-an-access-token), that can determine the region of the resource, by using the API Key.

If not, is there any way we can determine the region of the resource for an user?

Comment: `I'm wondering if Microsoft has an endpoint, such as the issueToken endpoint, that can determine the region of the resource, by using the API Key`. It's actually the opposite. "issueToken" endpoint must be called with a predefined region instead of giving you a possibility to determine a region.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem I want to solve is given an API Key (or access token), can I find the region associated with the API Key or access token?

Comment: Why do you need to answer the question "What is a region associated with an API key?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the region of your Cognitive services resource by calling the API endpoints below:-

Rest API [**reference1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/accounts/list?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0).

This API will List all the Cognitive Services resource in your Azure account with their details along with the location of the resource, Refer below:-

[image]

Rest API [**reference2**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/accountmanagement/accounts/list-by-resource-group?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)

This API will List all the Cognitive Services resource by resource group with their details along with the location of the resource, Refer below:-

[image]